# Python program performance and memory management

Tags: python

I've written primality test program in python but I'm certain of big issues. One being that program execution becomes very slow if the number to test is extremely big, I've used a generator. And it could be that the program utilizes a huge memory space. Is there any way the program can be optimized?

```
#define function
def isprime(n):
    return next((False for i in range(2,n) if n%i == 0), (n > 1))
#test it
nums = [i for i in range(101) if isprime(i)]
print(nums)
```

Comment: You're not using properly using a generator here. That would require the `yield` keyword. And it seems your isprime function always returns the same results for the same input, ignoring any iteration via `next` beyond the first value

Comment: @OneCricketeer it's generator comprehension `(a for b in c)`, without `yield`, but still a generator.

Comment: Beyond that, you're using the wrong algorithm if you want to find primes. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @bereal But `next` is expanding the expression, thus why I said "properly"

Comment: @OneCricketeer `next` only expands it until the first found divisor. The algorithm is also valid, except I'd rather use `sqrt(n)` for the upper bound.

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to enumerate the prime numbers in a range or just check if a single number is prime?

Comment: @OneCricketeer the generator returns only False values anytime the condition is met, so my interest is just to pick one of them, that's why I've used next. If no value is returned by the generator, a default expression is executed (n > 1) which results to either True or False.

Comment: @bereal Aim is to test for prime number, code below the function is just a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the fastest way to find all primes below a certain number is the `Sieve Of Eratosthenes` method. Checked on my machine, this algorithm is about 1000 times faster than the above one.

A nice comparison between different methods can be found here: [analysis-different-methods-find-prime-number-python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-different-methods-find-prime-number-python/)

Just in case the external link will change in the future, I'm putting here the code:

```
# Python Program to find prime numbers in a range
import time

primes = []

def SieveOfEratosthenes(n):
    # Create a boolean array "prime[0..n]" and
    # initialize all entries it as true. A value
    # in prime[i] will finally be false if i is
    # Not a prime, else true.
    prime = [True for i in range(n + 1)]

    p = 2
    while (p * p <= n):

        # If prime[p] is not changed, then it is
        # a prime
        if (prime[p] == True):

            # Update all multiples of p
            for i in range(p * p, n + 1, p):
                prime[i] = False
        p += 1
    c = 0

    for p in range(2, n):
        if prime[p]:
            primes.append(p)
            c += 1
    return c


t0 = time.time()
c = SieveOfEratosthenes(100000)
print("Total prime numbers in range:", c)
print("Primes: ", primes)

t1 = time.time()
print("Time required:", t1 - t0)
```